# i trying to learn editing .htaccess and my first example ever is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to learn .htaccess rewrite on my localhost what i did just enable mod_rewrite and checked it with    phpinfo(); everything is fine

now i create a php file : file1.php

```
<?php
    echo "file one working successfully";
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

and then created a second php file: file2.php

```
<?php
    echo "file two working successfully";
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

then i created an .htaccess file and write the following rewite rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file1.php$ file2.php
```

then i typed url http://localhost/test/file1.php i believe it should redirect to file2.php but nothing happens i similarly i tried some other code but didnt work how can i get out of it. i am using apache 2 on ubuntu 10.04 i have enabled mod_rewrite and checked it in phpinfo everything is fine then why my example is not working i m frustrated help me to get out of here.

Thank in advance

i am having all my files in the same directory that is test .htaccess too 
i find this an example at http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite and followed as it suggested but nothing seems to work

Comment: please dont downvote me i am learner i have googled and worked a tried a lot and finally i found noway out of this so therefore i am asking such a foolish question here please thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your .htaccess file is in the root directory, with the change below accessing `http://localhost/test/file1.php` should give return `file two working successfully`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/file1\.php$ file2.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Ulrich, assuming the two files are in `test` then surely the substitution string should read `^test/file2.php` otherwise it will do an internal redirect to `http://localhost/file2.php`

Comment: @TerryE Based on your assumption, you are correct, but I assumed that both files were in root :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file1\.php$ file2.php
```

Assuming htaccess sees . as a regex command, not as an actual ., you need to backslash it?

Comment: You're correct about escaping, but this will not fix his problem.